# Changing window size from restore down to maximize causes some content appear over another

Tags: c++, winapi, window-resize

I am using win32 api.When i restore down the window , i decrease width and height of list views but when i maximize it to its previous state , some of previously decreased-size window appears over the current list view.After i minimize the window , it unappears.

[image: This is the window without resizing]

[image: This is after restoring down]

[image: And this is when it has been maximized]

```
 InitCommonControls();
 hwndList1 = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW , L"" ,  WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | WS_BORDER  | WS_VSCROLL, middle-(18+width) , middleH-(18+height) , width , height, hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0); 
 hwndList2 = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW , L"" , WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | WS_BORDER  | WS_VSCROLL , middle+18 , middleH-(18+height) , width , height, hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0); 
 hwndList3 = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW , L"" , WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | WS_BORDER  | WS_VSCROLL , middle-(18+width) ,middleH+18 , width , height, hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0); 
 hwndList4 = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW , L"" ,  WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | WS_BORDER  | WS_VSCROLL , middle+18 , middleH+18 , width , height, hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
```

This is WndProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_SIZE:
            if (wParam == SIZE_RESTORED) {
                SetWindowPos(hwndList1, 0, 30, 40, 200, 120, 0);
                SetWindowPos(hwndList2, 0, 255, 40, 200, 120, 0);
                SetWindowPos(hwndList3, 0, 30, 190, 200, 120, 0);
                SetWindowPos(hwndList4, 0, 255, 190, 200, 120, 0);
            }
            else if (wParam == SIZE_MAXIMIZED) {
                SetWindowPos(hwndList1, 0, middle - (18 + width), middleH - (18 + height), width, height, 0);
                SetWindowPos(hwndList2, 0, middle + 18 middleH - (18 + height), width, height, 0);
                SetWindowPos(hwndList3, 0, middle - (18 + width), middleH + 18, width, height, 0);
                SetWindowPos(hwndList4, 0, middle + 18, middleH + 18, width, height, 0);
            }
             break;
        case WM_NOTIFY:
            if (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW) {
                LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW  lplvcd = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;
                switch (lplvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage) {
                    case CDDS_PREPAINT:
                        return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;

                    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
                        if (((int)lplvcd->nmcd.dwItemSpec % 2) == 0) {
                            lplvcd->clrText = RGB(0, 0, 0);
                            lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(193, 228, 255);
                        }
                        else {
                            lplvcd->clrText = RGB(0, 0, 0);
                            lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(255, 255, 255);
                        }
                        return CDRF_NEWFONT;
                }
            }
            return TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
                case ID_FILE_EXIT:
                    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case ID_STUFF_GO:
                    break;
                case ID_ABOUT: {
                    int ret = DialogBox(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_ABOUT), hwnd, AboutDlgProc);
                }
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can i fix it?

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're not repainting the window after moving the list controls.

Comment: Can we see more of the `WndProc` code, please?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve].

Comment: This code is a mess to read. Please take the time to properly format your code.

Comment: Please **properly** format your code. I'm not going to figure out, what `return CDR_NEWFONT; break; } } return TRUE;` is supposed to mean, unless you make it easy for me to see.

Comment: @Hans Passant - Actually, no it's not. Just looks out of place due to bad formatting.

Comment: hi,  Can you provide a complete code example? I tried to reproduce your question, but it not suceessful.

Comment: @Code-Lover I don't know I missed it. It's my [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVc2S.gif). There's no problem like yours.

Comment: @Strive Sun - MSFT I have changed my code totally and disabled resizing...Because of that i didnt provide a complete code example...Maybe it was because of my pc if there is no problem for you